# Accessing password manager apps in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

We're trying to open a modal on password text inputs in our iOS-only React Native app that will open third-party password manager apps. We have seen the same UI component for this in a number of iOS apps, with two examples being Airbnb and Venmo.

Here's an example from the Airbnb app:

[image: Airbnb example]

We've been searching high-and-low to figure out what this modal is called and how to access it. Does anyone know how these apps are accomplishing this?

Comment: You simply need to set the [content type](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextcontenttype?language=objc) of your text fields to username & password and iOS will prompt the user if a password manager is available

Comment: Thanks for the help! We're already setting the content type, and we're already able to access the native password autofill. This is a separate UI component that these apps are able to access via a button (notice the 1password logo button in the Input in my screenshot). It does not require 1password to be enabled for autofill and will open it separately.

Comment: This may be an older feature that 1Password and those apps worked on together prior to iOS 12.  Best practice is just to support the system approach, that way the user can access any password manager they have installed

Comment: @Paulw11 What you're talking about is different: those settings are for the built-in iOS password filling system. OP wants to allow third-party apps.

Comment: @Bill as of iOS 12 third party apps, such as 1password, can provide an extension that allows them to integrate with the system password features. As long as you set the content type on your text fields the user can access their passwords from iCloud Keychain or 1password or whatever other compliant password manager they have installed.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's done using [AgileBit's 1Password extension](https://github.com/AgileBits/onepassword-app-extension)